# Cannot connect to FoxPro Database from IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, foxpro

I am currently having serious issues connecting to a FoxPro database using an ODBC connection from IIS7.5

The database is on another machine than the IIS server and is accessed via a fileshare.

When I call the webpage from IE on the IIS server everything works fine. When I call the webpage from another machine I get a '[Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Cannot open file' error.

The application pool runs as a domain user.

When I run ProcMon on the IIS Server and call the page, when it is called from the IIS Server it accesses the offending file and then a whole bunch of other FoxPro files for that database.

When I run the page from another machine, I get an ACCESS DENIED error when it tries to access the first file.

It is a CreateFile call for a file called Comp_W.DBC that fails.

I checked and it is the same user that is invoking these calls to the fileshare so it is not differing credentials that is causing the problem. I even went as far as making the app pool account a domain admin to see if that might sort out the issue but still the same problem.

I cannot move the database onto the same server as IIS. I have tried to run the web application on the same server as the FoxPro database but I hit different issues to do with the fact that OWA runs on that server, and the 32bit ODBC driver causes conflict with an OWA dll that is loaded as a global module. I really need it to run IIS on a separate server from the FoxPro database.

The server(s) do not seem to be running kerberos as the delegation tab is not present when you administer users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

James :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the [Visual FoxPro OLE DB driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=14839) instead of ODBC, because it's newer, faster and won't conflict with OWA. That would let you move it onto the IIS server.

Comment: This was one part of the solution. I also needed to turn Kerberos on as well in the 2008 AD and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Past experience suggests that you haven't given the IIS user permission to access the folder where the DBFs live. When you run IE on the local machine, you're passing the credentials right through -- when you run it on another machine, I believe the anonymous user rules come into play. (Been a while since I had to debug this one, take it with a grain of salt.)